# In visual studio 2015, solution folder leads to a unsupported error

Tags: visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2015 community version and meet a problem. I created a solution folder, say "ABC", to classify projects. However, I got an error that The project 'ABC' is unsupported. Not sure what is the wrong.

Also when I created the solution folder, I could not find it in my solution folder in my file system. How can I create a folder in my file system automatically when I create a solution folder in visual studio?

Thank you.

Comment: A folder in a solution is a virtual folder. You can put things in many different "real" folders into that virtual folder. It will not create a new folder automatically.